# How to create desktop-launcher for .exe application which should be launched using wine inside its directory?

Tags: command-line, 18.04, bash, wine, launcher

I have an MS Windows application which needs new version of Wine. I have installed it locally to home-folder using PlayOnLinux.

I'm stuck with creating simple bash/dash/sh script to launch .exe application inside its folder. I tried standard *`pushd/popd`*, *`cd && exec`*, *`(cd && exec)`* approach but it failed.

What I need:

- Desktop-file as launcher for a script
- A script which:

  1. changes directory to .exe application's directory
  2. executes `wine .exe` inside application directory

Currently I'm happy with the following Python-code for wrapper script (to be placed in */usr/local/bin/wine32-wrapper*):

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os
import sys
import subprocess

if len(sys.argv) >= 2:
    path = sys.argv[1]
    wd = os.path.dirname(path)
    exec_path = ["/home/{}/.PlayOnLinux/wine/linux-x86/6.15/bin/wine".format(os.getenv('USER'), path), "{}".format(path)]
    p = subprocess.run(exec_path, cwd=wd)
else:
    print("\nUsage {} with one argument - full file path.".format(sys.argv[0]));
```

and .desktop-file (to be placed in *~/.local/share/applications/wine32.desktop*), for it:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon=mate-panel-launcher
Exec=wine32-wrapper %f
Name=Local Wine32-6.15
```

then I associate my exe-files with this wine script using Caja.

Is it possible to replace above python script with bash/dash/sh script with exactly same functionality?

Comment: Hi Norbert. is not enough to put xdg-open on the exec line with %F?

Comment: Thanks, @jpbrain, It is not enough, as .exe application reads data from its directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more deeper analysis I found good and interesting desktop-files for "Wine Windows Program Loader" which came from Wine packages. It has special options in [`Exec` field](https://sources.debian.org/src/wine/5.0.3-3/loader/wine.desktop/?hl=3#L28):

> `Exec=wine start /unix %f`

and forces exe-file to be launched in its directory.

For my case it may be adapted for *~/.local/share/applications/wine32.desktop* as shown below:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon=mate-panel-launcher
Exec=/home/user/.PlayOnLinux/wine/linux-x86/6.15/bin/wine start /unix %f
Name=Local Wine32-6.15
```

Thus the script part is not needed, we end with single desktop-file with special `start /unix` option.

Note: when Wine is installed from official Ubuntu repositories such "Wine Windows Program Loader" can be registered using commands like `mkdir -p ~/.local/share/applications/ && cp /usr/share/doc/wine-stable/examples/wine.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/` .

Answer (score 1):

For the Desktop entries there is a [Path](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s06.html) parameter available. Here is how the StarCraft II launcher (created during the installation by Wine) looks like:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=StarCraft II
Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/home/spas/.wine" /opt/wine-staging/bin/wine C:\\\\windows\\\\command\\\\start.exe /Unix /home/spas/.wine/dosdevices/c:/users/Public/Desktop/StarCraft\\ II.lnk
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Comment=Play StarCraft II
Path=/home/spas/.wine/dosdevices/c:/Program Files (x86)/StarCraft II
Icon=89A5_StarCraft II.0
StartupWMClass=starcraft ii.exe
```

Comment: The problem here is that `Path` is dynamic. I can't predict from which directory user will launch the .exe. Imagine the situation where .exe reads its .ini (or DB, or some resource) from the same directory.